# ¿Cómo puedo corregir mi código para que me de una lista plegable y formula conectando a mi base datos?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, formularios

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un sistema de inventario, pero en mis formularios que tengo, quiero incluir varias listas plegables y adicional quiero que en la casilla de p_venta me arroje solo el resultado.

**base de datos:**

```
      <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Base_datos');
    
    /* comprobar la conexión */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM genero");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_genero'] . '">' . $valores['genero'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_categoria'] . '">' . $valores['categoria'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM colores");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_color'] . '">' . $valores['color'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM marcas");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_marca'] . '">' . $valores['marca'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM medidas");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_medida'] . '">' . $valores['medidas'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tallas");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_talla'] . '">' . $valores['talla'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipo");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_tipo'] . '">' . $valores['tipo'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>
```

**Archivo .php:**

```
   <?php
  include 'verificar.php';
  $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_genero * genero FROM genero");
  $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_marca * marca FROM marcas");
  $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_categoria * categoria FROM categoria");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_color * color FROM colores");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_medida * medidas FROM medidas");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_talla * talla FROM tallas");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_tipo * tipo FROM tipo");
?>

<html>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Formulario Registrar Producto</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pages/css/registrar.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pin.it/3urbp4j">  
    </head>
 <body>
    </form>
      <selection class="form-register">
        <form style="text-align: center; ">
        <h4>Registar nuevo producto</h4>
        <form action="registrar.php" method="POST">
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="fecha"
            id="fecha"
            placeholder="Fecha"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="id"
            id="id"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Id"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="clave"
            id="clave"
            placeholder="Clave"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="nombre_producto"
            id="nombre_producto"
            placeholder="Nombre del Producto"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="descripcion"
            id="descripcion"
            placeholder="Descripcion"
            required
          />
          <select name="genero" class="controls">
            <?php 
                while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo '<option value="' . $valores['id'] . '">' . $valores['genero'] . '</option>';
                  }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="marca" required>
            <?php
             while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_marca'] . '">' . $valores['marca'] . '</option>';  
               }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="categoria" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_categoria'] . '">' . $valores['categoria'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="tipo" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_tipo'] . '">' . $valores['tipo'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="talla" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_talla'] . '">' . $valores['talla'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="medidas" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_medida'] . '">' . $valores['medidas'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="color" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_color'] . '">' . $valores['color'] . '</option>'; 
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="unidades"
            id="unidades"
            placeholder="Unidades"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="p_compra"
            id="p_compra"
            placeholder="P_Compra"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="p_venta"
            id="p_venta"
            placeholder="P_Venta"
            required
            <?php 
            $p_compra = 'p_compra';
            $a = '1';
            $b = '70%';

            $resultado = ($p_compra / $a) * $b + $p_compra;
            ?>
          />
          <input class="button" type="submit" value="Registrar"/>
        </form>
        </form>
      </selection>
    </body>
  </html>
</html>
```

En el  es la parte del código que debería de traerme todas las opciones que tengo en esa tabla, pero no las trae.

Ya eh modificado de diversas formas el código, pero hay algo que no detecto que está mal.

Utilizo visual studio code para desarrollar mi proyecto, eh descargado varias extensiones para que me sean de utilidad.

¿Podrían auxiliarme?

Comment: ¿Has hecho la prueba básica de la página de información? `<?php phpinfo();`

Answer (score 1):

```
Si lo que quieres hacer es un campo Seleccionador con opciones para realizar un alta, yo lo hago de esta manera,espero te sea de ayuda
 
Codigo HTML: 

    <label for="">Tipo de Usuario</label>
     <select name="tipo_usuario" class="form-control zoom">
    <option value="ADM">Administrador</option>
    <option value="EDC">Encargado de Cedis</option>
    <option value="ECF">Encargado de Cuarto Frio</option>
    <option value="VEN">Vendedor</option>
    </select>


Con PHP, solamente lo mando a llamar mediante el name = "tipo_usuario"
Codigo PHP: 
$errores='';
$enviado=false;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $nombre = filter_var(trim($_POST['nombre']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $apellidop = filter_var(trim($_POST['apellidop']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $apellidom = filter_var(trim($_POST['apellidom']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $fecha_nacimiento =$_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];    
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $tipo_usuario = $_POST['tipo_usuario'];

    //Validar campos
    //username
    $usuario = trim($usuario);
    if (empty($usuario) or empty($nombre) or empty($apellidop) or empty($apellidom) or empty($correo) or empty($contrasena) or empty($confirmar_contrasena) or empty($direccion))

    {
        $errores.= 'POR FAVOR RELLENA TODOS LOS CAMPOS<br>';
    }
    else
    {

        

        filter_var($nombre, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        filter_var($apellidop, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        filter_var($apellidom, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        filter_var($contrasena, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('

                SELECT *
                FROM usuarios
                WHERE usuario = :usuario
                LIMIT 1

                ');
            $statement ->execute(array(':usuario'=> $usuario));
            $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    
    
            if($resultado !== false)
            {
                $errores .= 'El usuario ya existe, por favor registra uno diferente <br>';
            }
            else
            {
            
                    if($errores == '');
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            $statement = $conexion->prepare('
                                INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, correo, sexo, fecha_nacimiento, estado, tipo_usuario, telefono, direccion)
                                 VALUES (:nombre,:apellidop,:apellidom,:contrasena,:correo,:sexo,:fecha_nacimiento,:status,:tipo_usuario,:telefono,:direccion)
                                ');

                            $statement->execute(array(

                                ':nombre' => $nombre,
                                ':apellidop' => $apellidop,
                                ':apellidom' => $apellidom,
                                ':contrasena' => $contrasena,
                                ':correo' =>  $correo,
                                ':sexo' =>  $sexo,
                                ':fecha_nacimiento' =>  $fecha_nacimiento,
                                ':status' => $estado,
                                ':tipo_usuario' => $tipo_usuario,
                                ':direccion' => $direccion                                
                                ));
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e)
                        {
                            $errores .= $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
                        }

                        
                        
                        if(empty($errores))
                        {
                            $enviado=true;
                        }
                    }
                        

            }   
    }
}

Espero te sea útil, cualquier cosa me puedes decir y con gusto te ayudo!
Saludos.
```

Comment: muchas gracias Kevin, lo voy a probar a ver si me permite visualizar mis datos de mi tabla que tengo en mi base de datos. Te lo agradezco mucho. Claro te daré molestias si no pudiese. Muchas gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

la extensión de las dos paginas termina en.php ?

Tal vez ese sea el error, estas metiendo codigo php a un html o puedes tener algun error de sintaxis de pronto no cerraste algun " o ';

Comment: Creo que no me hice entender.

verifica primero que tus archivos tengan la extencion .php (entra en la carpeta donde tus archivos están guardados y mira la extencion Ejemplo:
index.html 
si hay algún archivo que tenga la extencion .html cambiala a php para poder usar el lenguaje  )